# Writing SQL statement in sqlcmd to hide the milliseconds for column type of time

Tags: sql-server-2008, datatypes, sqlcmd

I have a table called `testtable` that have a column named `expire_time` of type [time]

The problem is that when I type the following in sqlcmd:

```
select * from testtable
```

It will return the following:

```
===================================
|   ID   |  expire_time           |
===================================
|  1     | 17:18:19:0370000       |
|  2     | 20:11:19:0680000       |
===================================
```

How should I parse my SQL statement such that it will display the following?

```
===========================
| ID   |  expire_time     |
===========================
|  1   |   17:18:19       |
|  2   |   20:11:19       |
===========================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the milliseconds, you can use either one of the following:

**Solution (Credit: Mr.Brownstone)**

```
SELECT ID, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, expire_time, 108) AS EXPIRE_TIME FROM testtable;
```

or

**Solution (Credit: BartekR)**

```
SELECT *, CAST(expire_time AS TIME(0)) FROM testtable;
```

For more information, please refer to their answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to remove the nano-seconds for display purposes you could convert the time value to a string using the below which will give you the format you desire:

```
SELECT ID, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, EXPIRE_TIME, 108) AS EXPIRE_TIME FROM TESTTABLE;
```

However, if you do decide to do this and then decide you need to perform calculations on the information, you would need to cast it back to a time value; which would give you the nano-seconds again but they would be set to zeros.

Alternatively, you could handle the formatting of the data in the object that is consuming it; for instance a SSRS report (which has the Format() function) or in an ASP.NET Web Form (which has a multitude of ways to handle this). It really depends on what your ultimate goal is that you want to achieve.

I hope this helps you.

Further Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also cast it to `TIME(0)`:

```
CREATE TABLE #testtime (
    _id TINYINT,
    _time TIME
)
GO
INSERT INTO #testtime (_id, _time) VALUES
(1, '17:18:19'),
(2, '20:11:19')

SELECT *, CAST(_time AS TIME(0)) FROM #testtime

DROP TABLE #testtime
```

Expected result:

```
_id _time   (No column name)
1   17:18:19.0000000    17:18:19
2   20:11:19.0000000    20:11:19
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to subtract the milliseconds from the time

```
select DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, GETDATE()), GETDATE());
```

so in your case

```
SELECT ID, DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, EXPIRE_TIME), EXPIRE_TIME) AS EXPIRE_TIME FROM TESTBASE;
```

in SQLCMD

```
c:\sqlcmd -S Servername -d DBname -q "SELECT ID, DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, EXPIRE_TIME), EXPIRE_TIME) AS EXPIRE_TIME FROM TESTBASE;"
```

check out this [POST on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286849/sql-server-remove-milliseconds-from-datetime)